# how can I detect the maximum size of overlay hardware via Direct Draw library?

Tags: directdraw

how can I detect the maximum size of overlay hardware via Direct Draw library?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there's no such kind of API to query that. You may only try. 
Try to create overlay/normal render buffer.  Query an API to  get the supported FOURCC code.
Try to set as many as back buffers as you want.